# Future method calling api sometimes returns null sometimes not

Tags: api, flutter, future

In this method, the output is as follows:

I/flutter ( 2928): 200

I/flutter ( 2928): null

I/flutter ( 2928): [Instance of 'Images']

This is causing snapshot.data to be null in my FutureBuilder as well.Any Idea why is this happening?

```
Future<List<Images>> getData( File f ) async {

List<Images> list;

// String link = "https://clothest.herokuapp.com/";
String link ="https://us-central1-velvety-rookery-274308.cloudfunctions.net/function-1";
var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(f.openRead()));
var length = await f.length();
var postUri = Uri.parse(link);
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);
var multipartFileSign = new http.MultipartFile('File', stream, length,
    filename: basename(f.path));
request.files.add(multipartFileSign);
request.headers.addAll({"content-type": "application/json"});
var response = await request.send();

print(response.statusCode); //200 OK

if (response.statusCode == 200){
  response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {

          var data = json.decode(value);
          var rest = data["Items"] as List;

          list = rest.map<Images>((json) => Images.fromJson(json)).toList();

          print(list.toString());


  });

}
print(list.toString());
return list;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to solve this problem by using another package instead of the HTTP package. **Dios** package is the best regarding HTTP requests. Updated code:

```
Future<List<Images>> getData( File f ) async {
  List<Images> lst=[];
  String link ="https://us-central1-velvety-rookery-274308.cloudfunctions.net/function-1";
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  FormData formdata = new FormData(); // just like JS
  formdata.add('File', new UploadFileInfo(f, basename(f.path)));
  await dio.post(link, data: formdata, options: Options(
    method: 'POST',
    responseType: ResponseType.JSON // or ResponseType.JSON
)).then((response) {
  print(response);
  if(response.statusCode==200){ //OK
     var responseBody = response.data;  //Map
     var rest = responseBody["Items"] as List;
     //print(rest);
     lst = rest.map<Images>((json) => Images.fromJson(json)).toList();   //instances of 'Images' object
     //print(lst);
  }
}



).catchError((error) => print(error));

return lst;
```